# why does iphone-xcode leak tool show a leak for this code?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks

I've gone thru my app using build/analyze and been able to resolve all issues.

but running under leak tool it detects a leak and says it comes from tvc:viewDidLoad where tvc is a tableViewController

it further references NSArray -> sectionlist

it shows a malloc refct=1
then a retain     refct=2
then a release    refct=1

here is viewDidLoad below followed by the dealloc and the header

I don't see where this is a problem? Am I missing something?

other than the code I've included, the sectionList is only referenced in 2 other places -

1. in numberOfRowsInSection

   return [[self sectionList] count];
2. in cellForRowAtIndexPath

   [[cell textLabel] setText:[[self sectionList] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

is this a red herring? ie; is it a real leak or is the leak tool only capable of showing the alloc but then not showing where the release happens in the dealloc when the tvc is unloaded later?

```
enter code here

/// code 
////////////////////////

// property
@synthesize sectionList = ivSectionList;

/*
*********************************************
build list of sections
*********************************************
*/
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];  

// alloc a local array and init with values  
NSArray *sections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];

// assign local array to tvc ivar  
[self setSectionList:sections];

// release local array  
[sections release], sections=nil;
}


/*
*********************************************
release ivSectionList
*********************************************
*/
- (void)dealloc
{
[ivsectionList release], ivsectionList=nil;
[super dealloc];
}


//////// header
////////////////////////////////////////
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tvc : UITableViewController
{
NSArray *ivsectionList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sectionList;
@end
////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 1):

leaks (or Instruments) is telling you where the leaked object is *created*.

most likely, a client is not releasing it.

a subclass may also be misusing this class, it's a good idea to make your ivars `@private` by default.

alternatively, you may want to try `atomic` read/write, just in case you're having a threading issue in this case.

(but yes, the excerpt looks correct)

Comment: using activity monitor I see an add memory, release pattern as I work my way up and down the path to and from this tvc -   15.13 - 15.23 - 16.42 - 15.28 - 15.14 repeatably - seeming to indicate that there really isn't a leak. but I do blow up after a bunch of operations so it might be telling the truth. will investigate further and post results later. thanks

Comment: This was a legitimate leak - took a while but I found it. The leak was elsewhere - an instance of this class was created and not released. The crashes were un-related.

Comment: cool. thanks for the follow up. there are occasionally leaks in the system frameworks, but that is less common.

Comment: @Mike wow 5 days to find out a leak... I'm not too excited on finding my own leak after 1 day now. :o